# Bootstrap Card - change width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So I want to change the width of the first column, it is taking too much space.
Tried to manually tweak

> `<div class="card" style="width: 3rem;">`

but it isn't having any effect. Why?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <title>Tela inicial</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center py-3" style="width: 800px;">
        <div class="container border rounded ">

            <div class="row mb-4">
                <div class="card-group">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 3rem;">
                        <h6 class="card-header colors-light-Gest">
                            Number
                        </h6>
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                          <li class="list-group-item">1</li>
                          <li class="list-group-item">2</li>
                          <li class="list-group-item">3</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <h6 class="card-header colors-light-Gest">
                            Atendente
                        </h6>
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                          <li class="list-group-item">Person1</li>
                          <li class="list-group-item">A second item</li>
                          <li class="list-group-item">A third item</li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <h6 class="card-header colors-light-Gest">
                            Data
                        </h6>
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                          <li class="list-group-item">14/04/2021</li>
                          <li class="list-group-item">A second item</li>
                          <li class="list-group-item">A third item</li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <h6 class="card-header colors-light-Gest">
                            Observation
                        </h6>
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                          <li class="list-group-item">14/04/2021</li>
                          <li class="list-group-item">A second item</li>
                          <li class="list-group-item">A third item</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Offhand I would say that the `flex: 1 0 0%` is overriding the width declaration. If you want fixed widths, then remove that declaration.

Comment: Also note that 3rem is quite small...are you sure you want that?

Comment: Oh thanks!!!! That was the problem haha, yes, 3rem it's too small, I was just trying random numbers. Thank you!! =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a flex layout. Use [flex-basis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) to set your width and disable [flex-grow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow).

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <title>Tela inicial</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center py-3" style="width: 800px;">
        <div class="container border rounded ">

            <div class="row mb-4">
                <div class="card-group">
                    <div class="card" style="flex: 0 0 3rem;">
                        <h6 class="card-header colors-light-Gest">
                            Number
                        </h6>
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                          <li class="list-group-item">1</li>
                          <li class="list-group-item">2</li>
                          <li class="list-group-item">3</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <h6 class="card-header colors-light-Gest">
                            Atendente
                        </h6>
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                          <li class="list-group-item">Person1</li>
                          <li class="list-group-item">A second item</li>
                          <li class="list-group-item">A third item</li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <h6 class="card-header colors-light-Gest">
                            Data
                        </h6>
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                          <li class="list-group-item">14/04/2021</li>
                          <li class="list-group-item">A second item</li>
                          <li class="list-group-item">A third item</li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <h6 class="card-header colors-light-Gest">
                            Observation
                        </h6>
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                          <li class="list-group-item">14/04/2021</li>
                          <li class="list-group-item">A second item</li>
                          <li class="list-group-item">A third item</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

But maybe `flex: 0 0 auto` would be better than `flex: 0 0 3rem`